# How to make stretchable chat bubble in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5-canvas

I would like to make stretchable bubble chat shape in Javascript. It should have gradient color as background and possibility to add border around the shape. The result would be something like this:

[image]

The rounded part would be stretchable and triangle will stay in middle in same size.

I have tried these approaches:

1. Draw SVG with `clipPaths`. Problem here was that triangle was not staying in same shape (it was stretching).
2. CSS `clip-path`. Problem here was that I did not manage to draw this kind of shape using basic shapes. unfortunately, `clip-path` is not supporting multiple `clip-path` at once.
3. Draw bubble in `canvas` and use as background. As bubble should stretch based on content inside, then the issue is to get events when content changed size and trigger `redraw` for canvas.

For now, `canvas` approach could be the easiest, but maybe there is some other solutions which I am missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `::after` to achieve the result

```css
.message {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 120px;
  width: 130px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  position: relative;
  background: rgb(2, 0, 36);
  background: linear-gradient(10deg, rgba(2, 0, 36, 1) 0%, rgba(9, 9, 121, 1) 35%, rgba(0, 212, 255, 1) 100%);
}

.message::after {
  content: "";
  background-color: black;
  height: 16px;
  width: 16px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -4px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%) rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="message"></div>
```

Comment: Unfortunality, this is with plain color, but I need a gradient.

Comment: You can add gradient color...Simple

Comment: and how to align color to triangle? thats the issue.

Comment: You gonna have to color it separately

Comment: Thanks for idea - helped a lot. Was overthinking here.